# como fazer upload de arquivos em pasta local com React.js

Tags: react, file-upload

Tenho um campo  onde o usuário faz o upload de um arquivo. Como faço para salvar esse arquivo em uma pasta local? Lembrando que o projeto está em React.js.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

Não é possível utilizar o React para salvar um arquivo em uma pasta local. A razão pra isso é a enorme falta de segurança, já que qualquer site poderia ter acesso ao sistema de arquivos de um usuário utilizando javascript. Por isso, a não ser em situações especificas, o browser não permitem esse tipo de manipulação de arquivos, mas existem alternativas:

1. Back-end próprio: Uma aplicação que executa localmente sem as restrições do browser terá acesso ao sistemas de arquivos muitas vezes utilizando bibliotecas próprias para isso, como o `fs` do Nodejs.
2. Serviços de terceiros: Caso o arquivo precise apenas estar disponível para uso, você pode optar pelo uso de serviços de terceiros, como AWS S3, GCP bucket, entre outros, que armazenam arquivos nos próprios servidores e disponibilizam URLs para seu acesso.